# Postgres, alter table dosen't change column definition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with a column name with size varchar(512), I have tried to modify its size to 2048:

`alter table table_name alter column name type varchar(2048)`

But nothing is happened.

So I have tried to delete column :

`ALTER TABLE tbl_name  DROP COLUMN name;`

and it works.

And than I add the column another time:

`alter table tbl_name  add column  name varchar(2048)`

But the column created is always `varchar(512)`

I don't know why it happens.

Comment: The code certainly works: https://dbfiddle.uk/ZKTE876B there must be something else you are not telling us.

Comment: Some kind of exciting DDL trigger built by an enterprising soul that limits column sizes because "512 ought to be enough for anybody", perhaps? Alternatively, some non-standard storage model provided by an extension with this limit? And, of course, always consider the more mundane explanations first, like looking at the wrong server/database/table, or forgetting to refresh metadata in your client. When a mystery happens, human error should always be suspected first.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Like what could it be?

Comment: You did not specify how you determined the `alter` did not work. What interface did you use? Most GUIs do not automatically refresh object descriptions and would not show the change even though the database had recorded it until the next manual refresh or logon.

Comment: **ADD to you question**, the answers to the following questions. 1) Where did you install Postgres from? 2) What version of Postgres. 3) What client are you using to run the commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify a column size in Postgres, you can add a new column with the desired size, copy the data from the old column to the new column, and then drop the old column.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD COLUMN new_name varchar(2048);
UPDATE table_name SET new_name = name;
ALTER TABLE table_name DROP COLUMN name;
ALTER TABLE table_name RENAME COLUMN new_name TO name;
```

or cast the data in old column to new data type

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN name TYPE varchar(2048) USING name::varchar(2048);
```

Comment: The above is not necessary, `alter table table_name alter column name type varchar(2048)` works just fine. You would need to invoke `USING` if you where downsizing the column size, but not for up sizing.